# Pandas Standard Deviation Expected to be Zero

Tags: python, excel, pandas, statistics

Generally, one would expect the standard deviation of n samples of the exact same number to be 0. However, using pandas' standard deviation tool I'm finding that there is a small (E-16) standard deviation for certain repeated values and I'm not sure what could be causing this. Interestingly enough, I notice the same error in Excel although not always for the same number of samples.

```
hereimport pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.1]*6).std() # 9.729507e-16
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.2]*6).std() # 0
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.3]*6).std() # 0
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.4]*6).std() # 9.729507e-16

pd.DataFrame(data=[5.1]*5).std() # 0
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.1]*6).std() # 9.729507e-16
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.1]*7).std() # 9.593423e-16
pd.DataFrame(data=[5.1]*8).std() # 0
```

[image]

Comment: It's numerical error. Floating point number have a maximum precision.

Comment: This is a float rounding issue. These values may not be representable exactly as floats. Even if they are, the result of dividing a float by `n` or `n-1` can be off by half an ulp, which will be around 1e-32. And when you sqrt an error of 1e-32 you get an error around 1e-16.

Comment: If you don't understand float rounding in general, the standard document is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf), although there may be simpler (novice-friendlier) explanations out there. If you do understand that, but want to know why exactly this error, edit your question to be more specific, and I can expand on my comment.

Comment: This is definitely helpful to know, but if I'm trying to avoid the numerical error is there something better than using the "round" function? @abarnert

Comment: The `round` function won't do anything useful at all here. If you don't get that, you really do need to read a tutorial on floats.

Comment: @abarnert My use case is trying to determine how many Std Deviations away from the mean certain values are. If I round the Std Deviation output to 4 decimal places for example, that rounds down to zero which helps me avoid the numerical error interfering with my calculations